# OpenLayers3 map creation not centering

Tags: openlayers

I have the following very simple code:

```
@map_center = [-32.951106, -60.669952]
@map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map-canvas',
        layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()})],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: @map_center,
          zoom: 5
        })
    })
```

It's in coffeescript, but you will get the idea. The problem is, the map does not center at all. It gets stuck in [0, 0]
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like [-4000000,-7000000] (using coordinate in epsg:3857).

With your coordinates:

```
center: ol.proj.transform([-32.951106, -60.669952], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
```

Comment: Great..! It moves! Could you clarify a little on epsg? I used the same coordinates in google maps and they worked ...

Comment: As I understand it, the coordinates I used are in degrees

Comment: Updated my answer to use EPSG:4326